# Bound Service with iBinder localservice continuous string update

Tags: android, binding

Following [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) (Extending the Binder class section) it is possible to get a string coming from Service in the Activity, simply pressing one button.

But how to obtaining string updates in Activity continuously? To better explain, if the Service data change ramdomly, how to get the same data (a string) in Activity too, without press any key? Because it seems that the value obtained is that of the time when values are requested to Service...

Snipped of Activity

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the LocalService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
        Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Snippet of Service

```
/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

Comment: If you want timely updates then why don't you want you call mService.getRandomNumber using a timer task just after service is connected successfully in onServiceConnected (ComponentName name, IBinder service).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It can be a solution, a scheduled system check for updates. But I was looking if exists something else, maybe a listener or something else. Something can write directly to the var in Activity. If exists, obviously...

Comment: you have local bound service,  right?  so pass an callback interface from your activity and service will call it whenever it likes

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that example that I provided above, was a sort of callback. I was wrong? Yes I have local bound service, but what do you mean for pass a "callback interface from your activity and service", please ?

Comment: create an interface with say myMethod(String) and let your activity implements that interface,  then pass it to the service and your service cab call myMethod

Comment: Solved with LocalBroadcastManager